# How to add a child row to a QTreeView row found by a specific column value?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

The following sample application is meant to display a QTreeView, populate it with 4 rows and add 12 more rows randomly distributing them as children between the 4 initially added. The parents must be selected by values of their UUID column (which can not be the first column in a row). All the UUIDs are unique.

I am trying to use `self.findItems(parent_uuid, Qt.MatchExactly, 1)` (where `parent_uuid: str` is the chosen parent id value and 1 is the index of the column where the ids are stored) to find the desired parent row but the result returned seems to be just an 1-element List of QStandardItem containing the UUID.

How do I change the code to achieve the desired behavior?

I use Python 3.7 and Qt 5.11. The UI code is generated with pyuic5 from a Qt UI XML file produced with QtDesigner.

Full app source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import random
import sys
import uuid

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklm'


def main():
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())


class TreeViewModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreeViewModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def populate(self):  # This is where the work is done
        self.clear()
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'UUID', 'Attr1'])

        parents_uuids = []

        for i in range(16):
            name = random.choice(LETTERS) \
                   + random.choice(LETTERS) \
                   + random.choice(LETTERS)
            uuid_ = str(uuid.uuid4())
            attr1 = str(random.random())

            row = [QStandardItem(name),
                   QStandardItem(uuid_),
                   QStandardItem(attr1)]

            if len(parents_uuids) < 4:
                self.appendRow(row)
                parents_uuids.append(uuid_)
            else:
                # TODO: Fix this else clause so it'd make the new row a child
                # The parent row must be found by its UUID column str value
                parent_uuid = random.choice(parents_uuids)
                parent = self.findItems(parent_uuid, Qt.MatchExactly, 1)
                parent.appendRow(row)  # Error


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.actionPopulateTree.triggered \
            .connect(self.on_action_populate_tree)
        self.ui.treeView.setModel(TreeViewModel(self))

    def on_action_populate_tree(self):
        self.ui.treeView.model().populate()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.actionPopulateTree = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPopulateTree.setObjectName("actionPopulateTree")
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionPopulateTree)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.actionPopulateTree.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PopulateTree"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findItems returns a list of the items that match the search, so in your case you just need to obtain the first item but still you can not add the items since you must take as parent the item in column 0 but you have obtained the item from column 1, so the other logical part will get that item:

```
parent_uuid = random.choice(parents_uuids)
items = self.findItems(parent_uuid, Qt.MatchExactly, 1)
if items:
    ix = self.indexFromItem(items[0])
    ix_col_0 = self.sibling(ix.row(), 0, ix)
    it_col_0 = self.itemFromIndex(ix_col_0)
    it_col_0.appendRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I've spent so many hours trying to figure out how to do this myself…